# double dash webkit prefix --webkit in chrome, single not working

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, blink

Have I stumbled upon something new?

My existing css with -webkit-transform (for example) is crossed over (disabled) when I inspect in chrome desktop v58 but when I add a dash to --webkit-transform- the css tag works.

Is this something new, I dont find anything about this when searching online

Comment: -- double dash is used for variables. Thats why chrome indicate it "understands" the term. It is not carrying out a css command per se.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates this phenomenon?

Comment: the reason for the confusion in the first place is that the css term -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) is being carried out by chrome but is listed, when inspecting, as a not active, crossed over term.

Comment: You seem to be confused by the comment and answer functions. The answer section is meant for answering the question - what you have right now should be part of the question itself. And your comment should be in the answer instead (and in a single answer, not spread out across multiple comments).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Here we can see what got me off guard and started suspecting strange stuff and buggs..]

The term is active and working but is listed as crossed over in chrome